# failed to create a channel in hyperledger fabric test-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i m using windows 10 pro , i've already run the example but i m getting this "Error: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": EOF

Channel creation failed" error during the creation of the channel .
here is the detailed error:
$ ./network.sh createChannel
Creating channel 'mychannel'.
If network is not up, starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb
Generating channel genesis block 'mychannel.block'
/c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen

- configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -channelID mychannel
  2021-04-27 00:22:56.240 WAT [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
  2021-04-27 00:22:56.248 WAT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
  2021-04-27 00:22:56.248 WAT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216
  2021-04-27 00:22:56.248 WAT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: C:\Users\houss\fabric-samples\test-network\configtx\configtx.yaml
  2021-04-27 00:22:56.253 WAT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 005 Generating genesis block
  2021-04-27 00:22:56.253 WAT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 006 Creating application channel genesis block
  2021-04-27 00:22:56.255 WAT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block
- res=0
  Creating channel mychannel
  Using organization 1
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=1
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=1
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=1
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/houss/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=1
  Error: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": EOF

Channel creation failed

Answer (score 0):

Please which link did you follow to install Fabric?

Comment: i followed the hyperledger fabric steps for windows , i've switched to ubuntu worked for me , what seems the problem is that the folders path are designed for ubunto , you have to change every "\" , since the idea is to run each organization on it's container , using ubuntu even on vm will make it easier